# Simple submenu glitch with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple menu on my website - when I click on a primary link it opens a submenu. However, if I click on another primary link it doesn't close the original submenu. How do I fix this?

It may be easier to describe with an example - click `Projects` then `More Projects`: http://jsfiddle.net/oxg7e07c/

```js
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
  // if there is any other element after a the  use
  // $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
  // also if you need any better effect then use
  // slideToggle() or fadeToggle instead of toggle()
});
```

```css
#menu-primary-menu>li>ul {
  display: none
}
#menu-primary-menu {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
}
#menu-primary-menu {
  position: relative;
}
#menu-primary-menu ul {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">More Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
          <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
            <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
            </li>
      </ul>
      </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Put `$('#menu-primary-menu>li>ul').hide();` before `$(this).next().toggle();`

Comment: `id`s have to be **unique**..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other menu items should be hide when opening a new submenu. You can use this by adding following line in the event handler.

```
$(this) // The element that is clicked i.e. a
    .parent() // The direct parent of the clicked element i.e. li
    .siblings() // All the sibling elements
    .find('ul').hide(); // Find will search for the `ul` inside the siblings and hide it
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide();
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
#menu-primary-menu>li>ul {
  display: none
}
#menu-primary-menu {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 200px;
}
#menu-primary-menu {
  position: relative;
}
#menu-primary-menu ul {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-27"><a href="#">More Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26"><a href="/category/projects/residential/">Residential2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="/category/projects/private/">Private</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

- The `id` should be **unique** in the *DOM*. If you want to have same behaviour for multiple elements use class instead of id(*which you already have*). I've removed duplicated id's from above demo/snippet.
- The `li` elements in the second submenu are missing closing tags.
- I will also suggest you to use `slideUp/slideDown/slideToggle` or `fadeIn/fadeOut/fadeToggle` for smoother animation/transition.

**Animation Demos:**
[Slide Effect](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/neaec98t/) [Fade Effect](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/neaec98t/1/)

Going further, you can also chain the two statements

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/neaec98t/3/
$(this) // Clicked anchor element
    .next() // Immediate next sibling
        .toggle() // Toggle the visibility
    .end() // Go back to the previous context, the context is changed when used `next()`
    .parent()
    .siblings()
        .find('ul')
        .hide();
```

Comment: You haven't noted the duplicate `id`s?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It's bad but it isn't the cause of the problem in question.

Comment: Yea but when you answer its good if you rectify and make OP correct it, so that he doesn't come up with question which would be just of correction type.. right?? :) @Alejalapeno

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I didn't really notice that, thanks for pointing. I was just focusing on the solution.

Comment: My apologies on the duplicate ID - this was my fault.

Comment: No probs @Tushar.. I just wanted your answer to be a good one.. :) since you always have a good solutions.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
  $("#menu-primary-menu>li>ul").not($(this).next()).hide();
  $(this).next().toggle();
  // if there is any other element after a the  use
  // $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
  // also if you need any better effect then use
  // slideToggle() or fadeToggle instead of toggle()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cwf5ogc/

or:

```
$('#menu-primary-menu>li>a').click(function() {
      $(this).parents("ul").find("li>ul").not($(this).next()).hide();
      $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sm6b6pvr/